# JS/NodeJS TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following statement which I'd like to have return any of these values if they are set, otherwise just return null.

```
var token = request.body.token || request.query.token || request.headers['x-access-token'];
```

However, whenever one of these is not set it throws a TypeError exception (cannot read property of undefined).

I thought something like this might be the solution but it's throwing the same exception:

```
var token = (typeof request.body.token === 'undefined') ? null : request.body.token || (typeof request.query.token === 'undefined') ? null :  request.query.token || (typeof request.headers['x-access-token'] === 'undefined') ? null : request.headers['x-access-token'];
```

Can someone suggest a better way of achieving this?

Comment: First you need to be sure that both `request` and `request.body` are defined.

Comment: Well if I knew that for sure then I wouldn't have this problem. I need to test whether they exist and return null if they don't.

Comment: Yeah, but you're checking for `request.body.token` right away while either `request` or `request.body` may be undefined.

Comment: `var token = request.body ? request.body.token : '' || request.query ? request.query.token : '' || request.headers ? request.headers['x-access-token'] : undefined;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cannot read property of undefined

That means that when you have `a.b.c` it is either `a` or `b` that is undefined, not `c`, so you can't test the definedness of `c`.

> Can someone suggest a better way of achieving this?

Avoid ternary operators for complex sets of tests. Go back to using `if` and multiple lines. It will be easier to read, write and maintain.

```
var token;
if (request) { // In a separate `if` because it is common to all the tests
    if (request.body && request.body.token) {
        token = request.body.token;
    } else if (request.query && request.query.token) {
        token = request.query.token;
    } else if (request.headers && request.headers['x-access-token']) {
        token = request.headers['x-access-token'];
    }
}
```